# "Invalid recipient" при отправке сообщения на почту с помощью mail

Tags: php, email

При использовании функции

```
 $to      = 'mylogin485634@rambler.ru';
    $subject = 'test title';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: admin@thisdomainlistedontheserver.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: admin@thisdomainlistedontheserver.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }
    else{

        echo 'not work';
    }
```

в файле  **debug.log** папки **C:\xampp\sendmail** Есть ошибка
**Invalid recipient** (У меня заведен такой логин на почте...)
Помогите отправить почту...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да уж, такой уж Рамблер коварный - не принимает от `admin@thisdomainlistedontheserver.com`, если он вам не принадлежит.

Проверьте `php.ini` на предмет наличия закомментированной строки (; нужно убрать)

```
;sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

А затем `sendmail.ini` на предмет правильного SMTP. Используйте реальные данные - от фейковых аккаунтов почтовые сервера давно научились не принимать ничего. Вот пример, если есть гуглопочта:

```
smtp_server = mail.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465 (или 587)
auth_username = your_id@gmail.com
auth_password = your_password_here
```

Более того, возможно, в `xampp` сам `sendmail` является обычной заглушкой, которая никуда ничего не отправляет. Есть и такие сборки.

P.S. Сервер необходимо перезапустить после внесения изменений.

---

Допишу, как ответ на комментарий. Опишу доступно.

Вы, скорее всего, не совсем понимаете принцип отправки почты. Не думайте, что `sendmail` - это некоторая программа, которая с локального компьютера *отправит* сама по себе почту на ваш ящик на `Рамблере`. Для того, чтобы послать почту, вам нужен некий рабочий (читай существующий) `SMTP`-сервер, в качестве которого может вытупать как и сам `Рамблер`, а также `Мэйл.Ру`, `Гугл` и прочие, которые предоставляют доступ к себе через `SMTP`. Вот, например, вы используете на локальном компьютере `Outlook` (пусть даже `Express`), `The Bat` или некий другой почтовый клиент, *в котором* у вас *почта* ящика `Мэйл.Ру`. Что происходит, когда вам с аккаунта `Мэйл.Ру` надо отправить почту на `Рамблер`? Ваш клиент, скажем `The Bat`, выступает в качестве `sendmail` - его модуль коннектится к `SMTP`-серверу `Мэйл.Ру` (допустим smtp.mail.ru) с помощью вашей же учетной записи на `Мэйл.Ру` (т.е. `username/password`) и *кладет* на сервер сообщение почты (в соответствии с синтаксисом протокола), в адресе получателя которого указан получатель на `Рамблере` (здесь будет уместно указать, что для того чтобы послать почту на ваш же `mylogin485634@rambler.ru`, достаточно подключиться к SMTP серверу Рамблера и отправить почту через него же самому себе, т.е. в качестве отправителя и адресата будет выступать все тот же самый `mylogin485634@rambler.ru` - тем не менее, для посылки почты вы используете `SMTP` - *свой* или другого домена - неважно). `SMTP`-же сервер `Мэйл.Ру`, *получив* от вас почту, отправляет ее на `Рамблер`. Ну а дальше оно *оказывается* в вашем же ящике `mylogin485634@rambler.ru` (зесь не буду расписывать подробности).

Так вот, подытожим: для отправки почты через `sendmail`, вы должны в параметрах `sendmail.ini` указать данные для `SMTP`-сервера, **через (подчеркиваю) который sendmail будет отправлять** почту, и само собой, адрес `SMTP` сервера должен быть настоящим и рабочим, а данные `username/password` должны соответствовать вашей учетной записи - иначе он попросту не *впустит* вас.

P.S. Параметры для SMTP серверов смотрите в разделах "Помощь" или "Настройка почтовых клиентов" на сайтах соответствующих почтовых сервисов, например для [Мэйл.Ру](http://help.mail.ru/mail-help/mailer/popsmtp) или [Рамблера](http://help.rambler.ru/mail/mail-pochtovye-klienty/1275/). Обращайте внимание на "Сервер исходящей почты" и порт, который используется - его надо будет вписывать также в конфигурацию `sendmail`.

И еще: некоторые `SMTP` серверы требуют авторизацию через `POP`, поэтому можно также глянуть на этот раздел настройки:

```
; если перед отправкой почты сервер требует авторизацию через POP, заполните эти поля
;pop3_server=
;pop3_username=
;pop3_password=
```